# ZF2 How do i hide message error after wrong routes

Tags: zend-framework2, routes

I want to return a 404 error after a wrong route instead of the php Fatal Error long message.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' 
with message 'No RouteMatch instance provided' i
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your module.config array within your Application module :

```
'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml'
```

Or just edit the `404.phtml` view file in :

```
Application/view/error/404.phtml
```

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation.
After changing the project, this template work fine, and i will debug my problematic project to find what's wrong.